# Changing single-product stock.php woocommerce brakes the site,

Tags: php, css, woocommerce

I've tried to change the style on the stock.php file from `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/stock.php` while overridden it by copying it to `mytheme/woocommerce/single-product/stock.php` as written in the description of the file, but for some reason it breaks the website and now even if i bring back the changes or delete the copy of the wrong code and file, when open the webpage in browser i get message:

> "Warning: include(/homepages/13/d767788347/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Competitions294574/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/archive-product.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /homepages/13/d767788347/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Competitions294574/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-core-functions.php on line 249"

If the copy stays in the folder the error changes to:

> "Warning: include(/homepages/13/d767788347/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Competitions294574/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /homepages/13/d767788347/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Competitions294574/wp-includes/template-loader.php on line 78 "

The file i try to just change the color looks like this:

```php
<?php
/**
 * Single Product stock.
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/single-product/stock.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see     https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version 3.0.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

?>
<p class="stock <?php echo esc_attr( $class ); ?>"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $availability ); ?></p>
```

Please help me to bring back the site live and change the color of the element showing how many products are in stock, also i want to change the text "X in stock"  to something different, how can i do this, please?

Comment: Do you have a backup? You would need to work with Woocommerce filters or some external plugins for Woocommerce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try:

1) Remove the files/folders you created inside your theme folder to override WooCommerce

2) Remove WooCommerce and Upload the latest version again - or update it from plugins if you have access to wp-admin (if you are using latest version already, change the version to some older version from wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce.php)

Comment: backup was the solution there, thanks for the advice!

Comment: Good to hear that you fixed your website, sorry I just thought that you don't have a backup. Have a good day :)